# Ionic tab menu not showing or can't slide in from right

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want two navbar buttons, one for search and one for sliding the menu
Using the below code,

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>{{ 'START_TAB' | translate }}</ion-title>

    <ion-buttons right>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="search()">
        <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
      </button>
      <button ion-button menuToggle="right">
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```

The menu button is missing altogether.
[image]

When I remove `menuToggle="right"` parameter, I get the below result:

[image]
and the toggle is from the left side as expected.

How do I make it toggle from the right and the icons be horizontally placed?

Comment: Do you want them on the same line as the Startseite ? or above/below it ?

Comment: the same line, at the right end.

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is a possible way to do it, I'll leave it up to you to play around

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
   <ion-grid>
       <ion-row>
          <ion-col-8>
             <ion-title>{{ 'START_TAB' | translate }}</ion-title>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col-2>
              <button ion-button icon-only (click)="search()">
                <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
              </button>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col-2>
            <button ion-button menuToggle>
               <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
         </button>
          </ion-col>              
       </ion-row>
   </ion-grid>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Ok so this part above should get you closer to the display you want for your header.

As for the menu opening from the right side, go to app.html or where your menu component is called and add **side="right"** to the **ion-menu** like so :

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" side="right">
```